# reference to procedure and self

Tags: delphi

When I'm in a `TForm` (say, `MyForm`) that has a procedure `oneProc` (`procedure TMyForm.oneProc`), if I do inside any procedure of `MyForm` something like `TThread.Queue(nil, oneProc);`, how does it end up that when `oneProc()` is fired that `Self` is well initialized to `MyForm`?

Can you explain why this works?

```
procedure TMyForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ProcA(ProcB);
end;

procedure TMyForm.ProcA(const Aproc: Tproc);
begin
  Aproc;
end;

procedure TMyForm.ProcB;
begin
  showmessage(self.className); // << this show TTMyForm (how?)
end;
```

Comment: Nothing in there is anonymous: all methods have a name (`Button1Click`, `ProcA`, `ProcB`). Of course `self` inside `TMyForm` will point to that instance (or class).

Comment: but in AprocA, Aproc is a reference to procedure (ie what I call anonymous)? not a procedure of object. so how self is propagated to ProcB?

Comment: Delphi documentation states that `self` references the object in which a method is called - in this case it's TMyForm.

Comment: @zeus `AProc` is a reference to a class method that carries its own `Self` pointer. The reference is used to call that method, thus passing around `Self`. See my answer for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, `TThread.Queue()` is overloaded to accept both `TThreadMethod` (non-anonymous) and `TThreadProcedure` (anonymous) parameters. Your text description is for code that would call the non-anonymous version. Your code example, on the other hand, is doing something a little different than what your described `TThread.Queue()` code would be doing. But in any case, to answer your question -

A non-anonymous method pointer actually carries 2 values within it -  one is the address of the method, and one is the value passed to the method's `Self` parameter (a method pointer is represented by the [`TMethod`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TMethod) record).

`TProc` is a reference to an anonymous method, and a non-anonymous method pointer can be assigned to an anonymous method reference. The [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi) even says so, in the section on "Using Anonymous Methods":

> Method references can also be assigned to methods as well as anonymous methods. For example:
>
> ```pascal
> type
>   TMethRef = reference to procedure(x: Integer);
>   TMyClass = class
>     procedure Method(x: Integer);
>   end;
>
> var
>   m: TMethRef;
>   i: TMyClass;
> begin
>   // ...
>   m := i.Method; //assigning to method reference
> end;
> ```
>
> However, the converse is not true: you cannot assign an anonymous method to a regular method pointer. Method references are managed types, but method pointers are unmanaged types. Thus, for type-safety reasons, assigning method references to method pointers is not supported. For instance, events are method pointer-valued properties, so you cannot use an anonymous method for an event. See the section on variable binding for more information on this restriction.

Internally, an anonymous method reference is implemented as a compiler-generated reference-counted interface with a single `Invoke()` method. When you write an anonymous method in code, the compiler generates a hidden class that implements `Invoke()` with that code. Any variables that the anonymous method captures are stored as members of that class.

When assigning a non-anonymous method pointer to an anonymous method reference, the compiler generates a class that captures that method pointer and then calls it inside of the generated `Invoke()`.

So, given the code you have shown, the compiler would translate it into something *roughly* like the following (I'm leaving out implementation details that are not relevant):

```pascal
type
  //TProc = reference to procedure;
  TProc_Intf = interface
    procedure Invoke;
  end;

  TProc_Generated = class(TInterfacedObject, TProc_Intf)
    FProc: procedure of object; // type of TMyForm.ProcB()
    procedure Invoke;
  end;

procedure TProc_Generated.Invoke;
begin
  FProc; // <-- calls FProc.Code with FProc.Data as Self! 
end;

procedure TMyForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Intf: TProc_Intf;
begin
  //ProcA(ProcB);
  Intf := TProc_Generated.Create;
  //TProc_Generated(Intf).FProc := @ProcB; 
  TMethod(TProc_Generated(Intf).FProc).Code := Addr(ProcB);
  TMethod(TProc_Generated(Intf).FProc).Data := Self; // <-- Self stored here!
  ProcA(Intf);
end;

procedure TMyForm.ProcA(const Aproc: {TProc}TProc_Intf);
begin
  //Aproc;
  Aproc.Invoke;
end;

procedure TMyForm.ProcB;
begin
  ShowMessage(Self.ClassName); // <-- Self valid here!
end;
```

That is how the `Self` gets from `Button1Click()` to `ProcB()` through `ProcA()`.